# How do I slide down a mobile menu with height 100vh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, slide

I have the following code in svelte.

When I click the burger (css omitted) it opens the navigation container.

I want the container to slide down in .3s. How do I do that?

I tried a couple things but alas, no difference.

```js
let open = false;

function setBurgerOpen() {
  open = !open;
}
```

```css
.menu-mobile-content.open {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-mobile">
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="menu-btn" on:click={setBurgerOpen} class:open={open}>
    <div class="menu-btn-burger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-mobile-content" class:open={open}>
    <ul>...</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `transition` to to slide down in .3s

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

This code will translate your menu down.

```
.menu-mobile-content {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.menu-mobile-content.open {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: This makes the vh always 100, so my whole screen is always filled with the menu

Comment: `transform: translateY(-100%)` will remove the menu to top, and cannot see the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The Svelte "way" would be to use [an `{#if ...}` block](https://svelte.dev/docs#if) and [transitions](https://svelte.dev/docs#transition_fn) instead of manipulating styles:

```
<script>
  import { slide } from 'svelte/transition'
  import { cubicInOut } from 'svelte/easing'

  let open = false;

  function setBurgerOpen() {
    open = !open;
  }
</script>

<style>
  .menu-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu-mobile-content {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
  }
</style>

<div class="navbar-mobile">
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="menu-btn" on:click={setBurgerOpen}>
    <div class="menu-btn-burger">{open ? "hide" : "show"}</div>
  </div>
  {#if open}
    <div
      transition:slide="{{delay: 250, duration: 300, easing: cubicInOut }}"
      class="menu-mobile-content"
    >
      content
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

See [this demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6384f07ec66d46a8b4f548827a8c36f4?version=3.44.0) using the code above.